# PromptSupport (SwingX) and nimbus L&F

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, swingx, nimbus

I have a problem with PromptSupport (SwingX) and nimbus L&F

I created a JTextField  and add a prompt to it by following code.

```
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    PromptSupport.setPrompt("promptText", textField);
```

The problem is that the prompt show in the textField correctly, but when I type some text to the textField, its background changed to GRAY.

I run the swingx demo, it has the same problem.
What I need to do to change the background of textField to WHITE when typing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

When swingx copied the source from xswingx they didn't look into the issues to see how that was [solved](http://code.google.com/p/xswingx/issues/detail?id=10).  I remember i recompiled xswingx with that fix for that issue, but now that i upgraded to swingx 1.6.3 it's back again. Please bug them in their bug tracker for my sanity too.
edit: though they apparently [already know](http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1476) sigh

Comment: updated the swingx issue with a link to the patch, assigned to Karl - hopefully will be fixed for 1.6.5

Comment: I ended up recompiling... its ok now. Though text areas still have some rendering issue (white strip overlaps with textarea border).

Comment: It was fixed on swingx 1.6.5, just updated the ivy.xml, works fine.